# What is the difference between Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows and Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

1. What is the difference between Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows and Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop?
2. Do they both support the exactly the same things as Visual Studio Express 2010 c#?

   1. Which is better? Visual Studio Express 2013 (C#) or 2010? The purpose - for school.
      THANKS!

Comment: It is stunning that such a broad, opinion-seeking question is so highly upvoted.  **1.** and **2.** above are both answerable with a bit of web browsing - i.e. some effort before asking.  A more focused question based on at least that much could make sense, but this pretty much ignores [how to ask a good SO question according to the Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as it stands. **(2.)1.** above is entirely opinion-based - with the exception of the given scholastic environment's particulars, which no one answering the question would know of course.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no research effort and only encourages regurgitation of basic web-search findings and opinion-based answers.

Comment: as a side note, when installed, **Visual Studio 2013 Express for Windows Desktop** is named/referenced to/as **Visual Studio 2013 Express for Desktop**

Comment: Two main differences according to website for the 2015 editions. Firstly the express edition does not work with pluggins. Secondly, the full edition is suitable for developing cross platform apllications whereas the Express edition is not. See link for more details. [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/onecode/archive/2014/11/12/differences-between-visual-studio-community-edition-and-express-editions.aspx)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

A comparison between the different Visual Studio Express editions can be found at [Visual Studio Express](http://web.archive.org/web/20141015013705/http://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-express-vs) (archive.org link). The difference between *Windows* and *Windows Desktop* is that with the *Windows* edition you can build *[Windows Store Apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/)* (using .NET, WPF/XAML) while the *Windows Desktop* edition allows you to write classic *[Windows Desktop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/)* applications. It is possible to install both products on the same machine.

Visual Studio Express 2010 allows you to build Windows Desktop applications. Writing Windows Store applications is not possible with this product.

For learning I would suggest Notepad and the command line. While an IDE provides significant productivity enhancements to professionals, it can be intimidating to a beginner. If you want to use an IDE nevertheless I would recommend Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop.

---

**Update 2015-07-27:** In addition to the Express Editions, Microsoft now offers Community Editions. These are still free for individual developers, open source contributors, and small teams. There are no *Web*, *Windows*, and *Windows Desktop* releases anymore either; the Community Edition can be used to develop any app type. In addition, the Community Edition does support (3rd party) Add-ins. The Community Edition offers the same functionality as the commercial *Professional* Edition.

- [Visual Studio Community 2013](https://web.archive.org/web/20160729090132/https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2013-community-vs.aspx)
- [Visual Studio Community 2015](https://web.archive.org/web/20160923072621/https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs)
- [Visual Studio Community 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/)

Comment: Thanks! You really helped me to understand the diffrences.

Comment: First link doesn't appear to work anymore. http://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-express-vs lists all the editions with briefs, but there's no clear (ie, with a table) comparison of the editions given

Comment: @kornman00 Thanks for the feedback - I updated the answer. Last time I was looking I didn't find a feature matrix comparing the different express editions in a table either. It's apparently only available for the commercial editions: [Compare](http://www.visualstudio.com/products/compare-visual-studio-products-vs).

Comment: +1 "It is possible to install both products on the same machine.".  Seems really silly to have to install separate products for web and desktop, but I guess it works.  I assume it doesn't actually install separate copies of VS express.

Comment: Notepad and command line are the best way to start TO HATE PROGRAMMING.
With Visual Studio, you can start with a form, one button and one textBox. That's all!

Comment: @T30 That's all! Well.... until things go wrong. And you're completely lost, since you never learned, how these things work. And post the bazillionth question on SO asking how to solve [this particular LNK2019 error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lnk2019). Read [Does Visual Studio Rot the Mind?](http://www.charlespetzold.com/etc/doesvisualstudiorotthemind.html) to see **why** I recommend learning what the individual tools are doing, in isolation, and thoroughly, before choosing a tool that hides most of the complexity.

Comment: I must say I really like the article you linked. Even so I don't think notepad is the answer. Yes, knowing that building might just be running `csc.exe` is something any skilled programmer in C# should know. But the way I see it, it's something you should know after you have written your first Tic Tac Toe in WinForms and after you understand the basics of programming. I agree that in situations an IDE may be obscuring some underlying processes, however experimenting in your environment can give you the insight into figuring out these at the moment you realize you don't know enough about them.

Comment: @komman00 The second link seems to also not work. They only list all express versions and system requirements, you'd think it's in their interest to specify the differences between the professional version.

Comment: "For learning I would suggest Notepad and the command line."  That's just mean man!  Love it!

Comment: At least suggest and editor with syntax highlighting.

Comment: Use use the IDE to get started. You create it from scratch when you know what you're doing. You got it backwards linux programmer

Comment: @Ernesto, I agree.. and I use and recommend **notepad++**.. not only for the syntax.. but also because of the 'work space'/project component; and, of course, the multiple tabs..

Comment: @SamuelNeff, I don't think it's silly at all to distinguish the two as separate IDEs and products, and I'm sure we see/get better build, update, and deployment planning and support this way. The retail versions of Visual Studio features and support (save for the whole team foundation component) is more of a head scratcher.

Comment: @IInspectable, you may want to make reference to (or elaborate on) the device emulator aspect of **VS2013 Express for Windows**.

Comment: @Brett: There are **loads** of differences between the two editions. Singling out a particular one, that appears to be irrelevant in context of the question, doesn't add significant value. I provided a link to a comparison between the editions, that sufficiently answers particular questions.

Comment: I think every point you just made is wrong.. the context of the question, the significance of the device emulator for the IDE, and that posting a link is sufficient as an SO answer. Furthermore, I think it's ironic that you would make a remark on context when your notepad and command-line suggestion is completely out of scope of comparing two IDE. Kind of ridiculous..

Comment: @Brett: I answered the question that was asked: "I want to learn/teach programming Windows desktop applications. Which VS should I pick?" Device emulator support is of little relevance in this context. The educational advice, however, is. The link I provided points to **additional** information, for those that may look for details not relevant in scope of this question. If you still insist that this doesn't make sense, feel free to reopen the question and provide an alternative answer.

Comment: For sake of completion, I would provide a link to the Wayback machine instead, the current link doesn't provide any information about express editions :
http://web.archive.org/web/20131113202411/http://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-express-vs

Answer (score 5):

Visual Studio for Windows Apps is meant to be used to build Windows Store Apps using HTML & Javascript or WinRT and XAML. These can also run on the Windows tablet that run Windows RT.

Visual Studio for Windows Desktop is meant to build applications using Windows Forms or Windows Presentation Foundation, these can run on Windows 8.1 on a normal desktop or on a tablet device like the Surface Pro in desktop mode (like a classic windows application).

Answer (score 3):

More importantly, the 2013 versions of Visual Studio Express have all the languages that comes with the commercial versions. You can use the Windows desktop versions not only to program using Windows Forms, it is possible to write those windowed applications with any language that comes with the software, may it be C++ using the windows.h header if you want to actually learn how to create windows applications from scratch, or use Windows form to create windows in C# or visual Basic.

In the past, you had to download one version for each language or type of content. Or just download an all-in-one that still installed separate versions of the software for different languages. Now with 2013 you get all the languages needed in each content oriented version of the 2013 express.

You pick what matters the most to you.

Besides, it might be a good way to learn using notepad and the command line to write and compile, but I find that a bit tedious to use. While using an IDE might be overwhelming at first, you start small, learning how to create a project, write code, compile your code. They have gone way over their heads to ease up your day when you take it for the first time.