# How to create dll for sql assembly using Visual Studio 2013 express?

Tags: c#, t-sql, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2012, clr

I am trying to created some `CLR` function using this [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878119(v=sql.120).aspx). In order to create the `dll` I have download Visual Studio 2013 Express.

The issue is I am getting errors like this on build:

> Error 1   The type or namespace name 'Data' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I am using the following template:

[image]

and using the solution found in the net setting net framework as target:

[image]

but is not working again.

Also, which version of the .NET Framework should I use for SQL Server 2012?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project type should be `Class Library` not `Portable` as on your screenshot.

Be sure you've included reference to `System.Data` assembly in your project.

SQL 2012 uses CLR **4.0** by default.

**UPDATE**

You should use VS Express 2013 for **Windows Desktop** (**not "For Windows"**) in order to create Winforms apps and class libraries. See [What is the difference between Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows and Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19435140/what-is-the-difference-between-visual-studio-express-2013-for-windows-and-visual)